# Can't use QList in class

Tags: c++, class, qt5, qlist

Compiles smoothly, but crashes when using the class. When I remove QList from the class the application works fine.

Is there a bug here that I don't see?

.h

```cpp
#ifndef INFOMODEL_H
#define INFOMODEL_H

#include <QString>
#include <QList>

class InfoModel
{
public:
    struct Active{
        quint8 quantity;
        quint16 validTime;
        QString name;
    }
private:
    QList<Active> actives;//Why Crash?!

public:
    InfoModel();
};

#endif // INFOMODEL_H
```

.cpp

```cpp
#include "infomodel.h"

InfoModel::InfoModel()
{
}
```

Comment: I suspect the real problem is undefined behaviour somewhere in code you haven't shown.  Adding/removing the `QList` just alters the symptoms.

Comment: I found a solution. If QList is used in a class, the class must be passed as const & in the argument. (const InfoModel &infoModel)

Comment: If that *appears* to be the solution then your class is probably not obeying the [rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Comment: The rule of three is work. Thanks.